# Replacement light fixture not working

Tags: light-fixture

I have a replacement kitchen led light fixture that is not turning on. Power is there: multimeter shows 121.6 at fixture.  Previous fixture obviously worked. There are two three-way switches for the fixture. I believe that I've wired correctly. I've tried two led fixtures. Critique as needed. Do I need to supply more info? Thank you. [image: supply]
[image: attached fixture wire]
[image: attached fixture with caps]

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say you fixed the 3 way switches after you removed the old light. If that is true you have them miswired. Also is your voltage between the black and white when the light is connected? Also from the black and ground wire.

Comment: Voltage was from black and ground when light was not connected. But I had done a test with a pen when it was connected and the wire was hot. Concerning the 3 ways, can you explain how I fixed them. Thanks

Comment: Update. Using a tester I have an open neutral (also hot and neutral give me 0 volts). Don't know how it happened. Anyway what does the process of fixing open neutral entail? I'm OK with someone telling me to hire an electrician. Thanks